# Designing an efficient continuous Questions-Answers feature for a Rails Application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, caching

I have a Rails Application where I want to present user with a sequence of Questions in a particular order. A user cannot proceed to the next question unless he has answered the previous one.

Here are some design issues I need help on for an efficient implementation:

> To fetch a list of questions for a user I need to make an expensive
>   db call. Once for a new session, the list if fetched I simply want the
>   user to see the questions in a particular order starting from the
>   first question. If the user had attempted some questions in
>   a pervious session he will jump to the question he last left off. How
>   to implement it efficiently? I believe I need caching here.

On rendering the views :

> How to render the view for this feature? I can have a controller with
>   the initial question template. When user attempts the question, should
>   I have question-answer options text updating with AJAX? Do I have to
>   use jquery for the purpose or any Rails helper could be of help here?

Any design help, rails features-gems I could make use of will be welcomed.

Answer (score 1):

My answer is not specific to Ruby on Rails, but it should still work.

First I wouldn't load data that you potentially won't use in advance. If you have 10 questions, and you only show one at a time, then I would just load the first and then once the user has finished the first, go ahead and load the second. No need to load all ten because maybe the user never makes it to question 10.

Assuming the user leaves pre-maturely, you can just make an AJAX call to pick up where you left off.

I would agree that you should cache those questions though.

The steps would look like this then:

1. First question - loaded via AJAX. Answer and progress saved via AJAX call.
2. If (1), then second question loaded via AJAX. Answer and progress saved via AJAX call.
3. Repeat until questions done.

This way you can use user/login information to make an AJAX call to pick up where you left off. I would imagine this would make your database calls much less expensive.

Comment: To fetch that single question I need to make an expensive db call everytime. In the system, a user selects a Topic. Depending on the topic chosen, I fetch the concepts under the topic, then the skills under each topic and finally the questions for each skill.